# Remote Call-In documentation - ProcessResponse()?

Tags: api, integration

I am studying integration patterns in Salesforce and one of the [examples](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/resources/img/en-us/240.0?doc_id=dev_guides%2Fintegration_patterns%2Fimages%2Fremote_call_in.png&folder=integration_patterns_and_practices) in [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.integration_patterns_and_practices.meta/integration_patterns_and_practices/integ_pat_remote_call_in.htm?_ga=2.16979129.1691147918.1670753968-1253122527.1666605239) on the Remote Call-In pattern describes the following sequence of events:

1. Login and get session ID via SOAP API
2. Query for records using SOAP API query() method
3. Execute logic in ProcessResponse() method
4. Insert, update, upsert or delete records using insert(), update(), upsert() or delete() SOAP API methods
5. Execute logic in ProcessResponse() method

Now I am slightly confused about the ProcessResponse() method being executed as I don't know what is meant by this. Is it a general way of saying "the caller then executes some logic on  his/her application to process the response of the Salesforce's SOAP API"? I did not find any specification to this method.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: _the caller then executes some logic on his/her application to process the response of the Salesforce's SOAP API_ - yes. that's what they mean.

Comment: @identigral Hi, thanks a lot. It is good to have a confirmation on these complex things. Cheers!